# Auto login with mechanize then django redirect into site

Tags: python, django, mechanize

Is it possible to open a live browser window with mechanize?  I have a view in django that automatically logs into an external website with mechanize.   After login I redirect the user to the site to a page past the login page but when django redirects, the user is not logged in.

How can I create a django view that will log the user in and the direct them to an internal page on a different site?  Is this possible?

Thanks.